# Output is not as expected

Tags: c++, pointers

The idea of my program was to print individual digits of n.
But instead it prints all the digits at once in the first line and a bunch of zeroes or garbage values in subsequent lines.
I want to access each individual number as we can do with arrays.
Suppose the input is 1234, why doesn't it print 1\n2\n3\n4?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int* n=(int*)malloc(1000*sizeof(int));
    cin>>*n;
    int len;
    len = log10(*n) + 1;
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        cout<<n[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `cin >> *n;` reads up to one integer from standard input and stores it in the first element of `n`.  All the other elements in that array are uninitialized.  It's not clear what you expect.  Yes, you're printing individual elements of `n`, but they have no guaranteed value.

Comment: Dont use `malloc()` in C++, use `new[]` instead, or better `std::vector`

Comment: I've read over your description multiple times, because it baffles me.  Based on your description of the output, I _think_ that by "elements" you actually mean "digits".  When you say "elements of n", a programmer sees the array `n` and assumes you're talking about all the elements in that array.  If you want to print the _digits_ on a _single integer_ you don't need an array, or any heap allocations.  You do need a loop, and some very simple math that is basically long division.  You can very likely find many questions on Stack Overflow that have a solution to this problem.

Comment: Alternatively, just read in a string and print the characters ;)

Answer (score 1):

When you `cin >> *n`, you don't read the number digit by digit, but read in as a whole.

So when you `cin >> *n` and type in `1234`, `*n` becomes `1234`.

If you want to print all the individual digits, like `1\n2\n3\n4`, you need to separate the digits for yourself:

```
int pos = 1;

while (*n != 0)
{
    n[pos] = n % 10;
    n /= 10;
    ++pos;
}

for (--pos; pos > 0; --pos)
{
    cout << n[pos] << endl;
}
```

However, the easiest approach is to read in the number as a string, not a number, then print out the characters, that is the digits, one by one.

```
char str[1000];

cin >> str;

for (char *s = str; *s; ++s)
{
    cout << *s << endl;
}
```

You can also convert the number into a string, and do the same:

```
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

...

char str[1000];

sprintf(str, "%d", *n);

for (char *s = str; *s; ++s)
{
    cout << *s << endl;
}
```

------- Original Answer:

If you want to print the first element of `n`:

```c
cout << *n;
```

or

```c
cout << n[0];
```

Your code

```c
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        cout<<n[i]<<endl;
    }
```

means

```
cout << n[0] << endl;
cout << n[1] << endl;
cout << n[2] << endl;
 
...

cout << n[len-1] << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

`n` is declared as a pointer to a memory location which can store `1000` integer entities. When you use `cin>>*n;`, an integer value is read as input and store at the first memory block among the `1000` blocks. The individual digits of the integer are not stored in separate blocks, hence you can't print them separately.

For example, if the input is `123`,
`n[0]` stores `123`, `n[1],n[2],...n[999]` stores junk values.
To store a value in `n[1]`, you will have to use `cin` again.

Comment: Let's correct your terminology, because it is misleading.  There is only one memory block.  It is `1000 * sizeof(int)` bytes in size.  It is being used as an array of integers.  When you refer to a piece of data at a specific index of an array, call that an _array element_.  Don't call it a memory block.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason you think that

```
int* n=(int*)malloc(1000*sizeof(int));
cin>>*n;
```

will read a number and put each digit in a different element of the dynamic array `n`. If that happened then the rest of your code would work (kind of). But of course it doesn't. Instead the number read is put into `*n` (or, same thing, `n[0]`) and the rest of the dynamic array elements are uninitialised, which explains the garbage values you see.

I'm struggling to understand why you thought your code might behave in the way you wanted. I guess you are just an optimistic person and think that if you wish hard enough the compiler will understand. This seems to be quite a common attitude among beginners. Unfortunately programming isn't like that.